# Mock a private key for jwt signing

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, jwt, ts-jest

I am using [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#readme) in my nodejs+typescript project.  Now, I want to test my function which accepts private key (as string).

```
import { sign } from 'jsonwebtoken';
//function to test
function generateToken(privateKey: string) {
  const payload = {...};
  return sign(payload, privateKey);
}
```

My jest test:

```
describe('token generator', () => {
  it('', () => {
     // I mock the private key in my test
     const pKey = 'dummy_pkey';

     const token = generateToken(pKey);
      ...
   })
```

When I run the jest test, I get the following error pointing at production code `return sign(payload, privateKey)` :

```
error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
```

Apparently the private key is invalid for `jsonwebtoken` library.  So, what is the best way to mock a private key for signing jwt token in jest?

**----------- update ---------**

I tried using crypto provided by nodeJs:

```
import { generateKeyPairSync } from 'crypto';

describe('token generator', () => {
  it('', () => {
      const { privateKey } = generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
          modulusLength: 2048,
       });
     const token = generateToken(privateKey);
      ...
   })
```

But I am getting the same error:  `error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line`, why? (I know it is because PEM is missing a start line, but why, where am I wrong? using the jsonwebtoken & crytpo for private key in test)

Comment: You need to generate key pair using `crypto` library https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptogeneratekeypairsynctype-options (sync or async) and use the generated keys

Comment: I used & same error ,  please see my update.

Comment: the vendor has already tested it works https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/blob/master/test/rsa-public-key.tests.js

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, it doesn't change the fact that something wrong with my code, and that's why I post this question. Either I used it in a wrong way or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide encoding options for you public and private key when generating the key pair. I don't know what the defaults are but this

```
const { privateKey, publicKey } = generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
    modulusLength: 2048,
    publicKeyEncoding: {
      type: 'spki',
      format: 'pem'
    },
    privateKeyEncoding: {
      type: 'pkcs8',
      format: 'pem',
    }
  })
```

works for me when I use it with `jwt.sign(payload, privateKey, signOptions)`

Also the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptogeneratekeypairsynctype-options) state

> When encoding public keys, it is recommended to use 'spki'. When encoding private keys, it is recommended to use 'pkcs8' with a strong passphrase, and to keep the passphrase confidential.

Comment: I added the encoding options for both keys, but still get the same error. Now I am thinking the issue is the signing code with jsonwebtoken library, `sign(payload, JSON.Stringfy(privateKey));`,  probably because of the `JSON.Stringfy(privateKey)` how can I pass the private key to the sign()?

Comment: Why are you using `JSON.stringify(privateKey)`? The `privateKey` is already a string in the correct format and not a JSON object. (Although it might have been when you were still missing the encoding options). `JSON.stringify(somestring)`  will surround that string with quotes, thus you are actually passing `"----- BEGIN ..... -----"` **with doublequotes** to `jwt.sign` which will of course fail.

Comment: You didn't mention that `JSON.stringify` anywhere in your question

Comment: It was not returning string at some point, I don't remember & added that stringfy but now everything works, thanks.